# Access values using javascript

Tags: javascript

Well I'm trying to load some dataset to Chart js. I'm performing an ajax request to my server and the return is a Laravel Collection in this format:

```
"23-August-16" => array:3 [▼
      "day" => "23-August-16"
      "total" => 22
      "partial" => 9
    ]
    "24-August-16" => array:3 [▼
      "day" => "24-August-16"
      "total" => 23
      "partial" => 10
    ]
```

Now from Chart js i want to assign the keys to the corresponding values.

So I have:

```
labels: Object.keys(data), //this is ok


 datasets: [
               {
                   label: "Total Employees",
                   backgroundColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.31)",
                   /* Chart js options */
                  data: Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key]) //here is not working
               }, 
           ]
```

I want to access the total property but i cannot find the way to get the value. I'm performing a mapping but after that i can't find the way to get the total number.

Thanks

PS: this is json output:

```
{
23-August-16: {
day: "23-August-16",
total: 22,
partial: 9
},
24-August-16: {
day: "24-August-16",
total: 23,
partial: 10
},
25-August-16: {
day: "25-August-16",
total: 25,
partial: 11
},
26-August-16: {
day: "26-August-16",
total: 33,
partial: 11
},
```

And I'm using Chartjs

Comment: Can you please post the data as JSON?

Comment: You might want to add the tags 'chart.js' and 'chart.js2' because people check those